# SAS Output window vs Results Viewer

Tags: sas, output

Hi i just installed sas 9.4 on laptop (running windows 8). Every time I submit a program results viewer is launched and the sas "report" (just output I guess) goes there instead of going to the output window. I just want to know if its possible to make the output go out of the output window instead of the results viewer.

Also if you could explain the difference between the two I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comprehensive responses :)

Answer (score 2):

The "Output" window is for the Listing destination.  This is the Pre-SAS 9.3 default method for viewing output.  Starting with SAS 9.3, they switched to HTML being the default method for viewing output.

While the new method is graphically nicer and easier to share output with others, if you prefer the listing destination, you can change that to be your default.

Go to Tools -> Option -> Preferences, select the Results tab, and uncheck "Create HTML", and check "Create Listing".  (Or leave both checked, and get both results.)

See the [New Output Defaults documentation page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/whatsnew/64209/HTML/default/viewer.htm#newoutputdefaults.htm) for more details.